# Pro-p topology on free group

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, profinite-groups, semigroups-and-monoids

Let $H$ be a finitely generated subgroup of the free group $F(A)$ and $G_P$ the pseudovariety of all finite $p$-group with $p$ fixed prime number.  We endow $F(A)$ with the pro-$G_p$ topology. Suppose that $H$ is $p$-dense. What can we say about the $p$-kernel of the transition monoid of $H$?

Comment: You should give the definitions you are using. By the *transition monoid* of $H$, do you mean the finite inverse monoid associated with the DFA accepting $H$? Is the $p$-kernel of a finite monoid $M$ the intersection of all sets $f^{-1}(1)$ where $f$ is a relational morphism from $M$ into a finite $p$-group? And what do you mean by $H$ is $p$-dense?

Comment: You are right about the definition of transition monoid and $p$-kernel. By $p$-dense I mean the $p$-closure of the subgroup $H$ is $F(A)$.

Comment: If we denote by $M(H)$ the transition monoid of $H$ and $K_{G_p}(M(H))$ be the p-kernel of $M(H)$, I want to know when the equality $M(H)=K_{G_p}(M(H))$ holds. Is it true if $H$ is p-dense?

Comment: Being p-dense is equivalent to the p-kernel acting transitively on the Stallings graph.  I don't immediately see why this forces the p-kernel to be everything